# Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods, xcode7

I am using Xcode Version 7.0.1 (7A1001) with `Cocoapods`.

My app builds & runs fine on my simulator and device.

When I try to archive the project I get this error:

[image]

```
xcodebuild -project InstaApp.xcodeproj -scheme TryProjects
```

When I use command line build, I get this error:

[image]

I tried getting rid of `Alamofire` but then the error moved on to the next import which is `SwiftyJSON`. I got rid of that then it moved on to `Alamofire` from the next file.

I tried `Cocoapods` reinstalling, changing pods, removing pods, compiler optimizations, deleting test cases, clean building, changing compile order, removing frameworks, readding frameworks, almost everything on the internet about this subject and more. But still, I cannot archive my project.

I had no problem 5 days ago. I didn't update Xcode or anything since then. Changed a few Cocoapods settings, added some new pods and thats it. What could be the problem here?